# Login in a different subdomain in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, authlogic

I´ve set an SSL certificate on Heroku to secure a subdomain: https: // secure.mydomain.com

Now, I need:

1 - Route the root of my site to that secure login page. When user hits http: // mydomain.com goes to https: // secure.mydomain.com/user_session/new

2 - Make my Authlogic login page always redirect to this secure subdomain, but all the others pages run in default http: // mydomain.com/...

Is that possible? Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to redirect to secure subdomain. Checkout this [tutorial / blog post](http://devmeat.com/show/791625) on the setting up sub-domains in a Rails app. Especially, checkout the SubdomainAccounts::default_account_url method in the section **Controller / Handling Requests**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ssl_requirement](https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement) - it allows you to declaratively set which pages require and do not require SSL. It's very easy to get set up and running.

Comment: Hi Andy, I´ve checked this plugin out, but I did not see if it´s possible to work with different subdomains. I only want to use secure subdomain for login action.